# Avoid server calls for loose resources that do not exist

Tags: java, applet, http-status-code-404

I'm developing an applet application which is compiled on Java 1.5 (compatible with 1.5+).
It contains some resource property files that are bundled together in the same jar, which lies parallel to the Java package.

Whenever I access that resource file through applet it makes a request to server from where the applet is been downloaded. After that it reads the files from the jar and works as it used to be but I don't want it to make server request for those files.

This is how my java code access the resource file.

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources/properties/Messages", locale);
```

I tried access in both ways:

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.properties.Messages", locale);
```

Both it had the same behaviour.

Note: Those resources are not available as loose resources in my web app.

Comment: Most of my users were using Java 1.5 plugin. So I was using `object` and `embed` tag to run my applet.

Comment: The default before JNLP based applets was to download all resources eagerly.

Comment: @AndrewThompson If so why the applet requests the resources when ever it runs..

Comment: Do the web-logs suggest that?  Is it indicated by a packet sniffer such as [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark)?  The Java Console can provide quite misleading information.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I got these details from server logs.. I was analyzing my server log for 404 and 500 responses at that time I came across these `/resources/properties/Messages_en_US.properties
/resources/properties/Messages_en.properties
/resources/properties/Messages.class` which are present and used inside the applet jar.

Comment: +1 for your keen attention of the server logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I got these details from server logs.. I was analyzing my server log for 404 and 500 responses ..

The [404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) (not found) & [500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) (server error) messages can be expected because the plug-in is trying to check if the cached resources are up to date.  To do that, it needs to check the time last updated on the server version of the resource.

The complicating factor is that the resource can be expected to be in a Jar mentioned in the `archive` attribute of the applet ***or*** it can be a 'loose file' on the same path as the `codebase` specified.  So if a resource is in the following path of a Jar:

```
/resources/properties/Messages_en_US.properties
```

The JVM will also check

```
${codebase}/resources/properties/Messages_en_US.properties
```

as well as each Jar.

To fix them, see the [`codebase_lookup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/special_attributes.html#codebase) parameter. This use-case needs:

```html
<param name='codebase_lookup' value='false' >
```

That tells the JVM that there are ***no*** resources stored as loose files on the class-path, and only Jars are to be searched.  It should stop the `404`/`500` messages being reported as often (for newer JREs that understand that parameter).

Comment: Upon testing I found that it works good for **JRE 1.6+** and fails below that, any how that would reduce my pain.. Thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was unable to find the exact version it was introduced.  You might find it was 1.6.0_10+ in which a lot of changes were introduced.  Still, with most JREs these days configured to auto-update, it should result in less pain over time. :)

Comment: Yes around 90+% of users are using JRE 1.6+ :D

Comment: Huh.  One of the few version/usage stats. I've ever heard.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the inner details of the Java Plug-in's caching of applets, but if your applet is using a .jnlp descriptor, I would try adding `download="eager"` to the descriptor's `<jar>` element.

You can also try defining your ResourceBundles as classes rather than .properties files.  For instance:

```
package resources.properties;

import java.util.ListResourceBundle;

public class Messages
extends ListResourceBundle  {
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        return new Object[][] {
            {"entry1", "Some message text"},
            {"entry2", "A different message"},
            // etc.
        };
    }
}
```

Just like properties files, you can define them for as many locales as you wish:

```
package resources.properties;

import java.util.ListResourceBundle;

public class Messages_es
extends ListResourceBundle  {
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        return new Object[][] {
            {"entry1", "Some message text in Spanish"},
            {"entry2", "A different message in Spanish"},
            // etc.
        };
    }
}
```

If you define ResourceBundle subclasses, it's a good idea to remove the corresponding .properties files.

Comment: Jnlp support for applet was provided from Java 1.6.10. Where as mine also runs in Java 1.5+